# css blur filter's edges become solid during translateY transition

Tags: css, transform, css-animations, translate, css-filters

I have an element with a `-webkit-filter: blur(10px);` applied to it.  I'm using a CSS animation to move the element up and down with it's translateY property.  When the element is animating or transitioning the blur remains but the edges become hard.  When the animation or transition ends the the edges become blurred again like they're suppose to.  I made a demo that shows examples of the notes that follow it.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/bofahekuko/1/edit?html,css,output

**I Tried Fixing it With:**

- adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` to the animating element.
- forcing hardware acceleration on the animating element and adding `backface-visibility: hidden` on the parent

**Things of Note**

- Happens with both CSS transitions and animations
- If you move the element up and down via the CSS top property the blur filter renders correctly.

**Browser Testing**

- Bug appears in Google Chrome (running Version 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit)) as well as in Canary.
- Both Firefox and Safari (iOS and Desktop) correctly render the blur filter during the animation.

I'd really like to be able to run the animation with the translateY transition property instead of the top property.  If there really isn't a fix it'd still be interesting to know what exactly is going on here to cause the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Not a solution, but it has started happening in 50. in 49 works ok

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that's probably **caused** by hardware accceleration - the GPU is just moving the original blurred content without updating its background.

To fix, don't use translate or use another trick to disable hardware acceleration (like simultaneously animating margin or padding)